# 'Like' using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-access-token

I am trying to like a post using the Facebook Graph API, I have the `access_token` with required permissions (`publish_actions`,`publish_stream`). The method I discovered on the internet is

```
POST: /148151888659853/likes?access_token=XXXXXX
```

I tried this, it works **but** only when the post(status update) is made by the same user as the `access_token`. I am not able to like post made by others (the status update is Public). How to do this?

When trying to like a post made by someone else, the error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what permissions you ask for when you request access token?

Comment: All the permissions that I ask are `email,publish_actions,user_about_me,user_likes,user_website,offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,status_update`

Comment: try using only one permission out of `publish_stream` and `publish_actions`.

Comment: I already have both the permissions. I have listed them above.

Comment: try using only one of them at a time.

Comment: I guess that will not work as, the permissions are used only when required. But I will try for the Confirmation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16970/discussion-between-sushil-kumar-and-akshat-mittal)